# celery: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children (with concurrent.futures)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, celery, concurrent.futures

In Python (3.6) I try to create processes (with multiprocessing) in a celery task (celery 3.1.17) but it gives the error:

```
daemonic processes are not allowed to have children
```

*code*

```
def mp():
  with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=90) as executor:
                    data = executor.map(pdfocr,[no for no in list(json.keys())])
```

Comment: It is probably related to the Celery using Billiard for process management. If you could refactor your code to use Billiard then it should work I think.

Comment: actually concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor is not available in Billiard and billard pool method is not working(don't know why) .- @DejanLekic

Comment: I would be very much surprised if Billiard was aware of concurrent.futures.* ...

Answer (score 4):

Start worker with `-P threads` argument:

`celery worker -P threads`

Celery version >= 4.4.0 has been officially supported

Refer: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4525#issuecomment-566503932

Answer (score 0):

Try use `billiard` package can fix this issue. I fixed the same issue when using `prefect` & `dask`.

```py
import billiard
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
ProcessPoolExecutor(mp_context=billiard)
```